# Controlling fan speed and temperature on 2011 iMac running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Hardware Apple Inc. iMac12,1

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, temperature, fan

I have been trying to cool this machine down as it had burnt its power supply couple times before and it`s running really warm. I was able to manually control fans in Ubuntu for a long time, but lately all those tools either got abandoned or are creating wrong paths in the system that I don`t have enough knowledge to fix manually.
Does anyone know of some workaround or any tool to control fan speed and cool the machine down a little bit?